# Port of Statpress to CodeIgniter

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter, port

I was wondering if anyone has ported the wordpress plugin Statpress into a CI library.

If they hadn't, would this be worthwhile doing?

Comment: Why not just use Google Analytics or the like?

Comment: No support for spiders.  Anything that can't do javascript is not recorded.

Answer (score 1):

You could defiantly do it. A CI library is just a basic php class. I'm not familiar with statpress but im sure they are using a php class to do it. then just log the results with the ci db...